# Very simple macro expanding command line program in Linux and Windows

Tags: windows, gratis, linux, command-line, macros

I am trying to create a workflow in which a single Markdown source document will spit HTML and LaTex friendly Markdown files. Since my content editor uses PC I need him to work on source document but also able to see output in HTML or LaTeX.

I am looking for a simple macro expanding software which will process my macros and create necessary doc both in Linux and Windows.

#### Mock example

My Source Markdown File

```
{@ verse @}
| first line
| second line
{@ verse @}
```

OUTPUT

```
HTML-friendly Markdown                   LaTex Friendly Markdown

<div id="" class="verse">                     \begin{verse}
| first line                                  | first line   
| second line                                 | second line
</div>                                        \end{verse}
```

#### In short

The macro expanding software should be:

1. Simple
2. Available in Linux and Windows

Comment: Are you willing to install [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com)?

Comment: Yes, Cygwin can be installed

Comment: I like [autohotkey](https://autohotkey.com/).  You could make it to traverse a document and macro-replace text.  It runs on just about anything and is relatively simple to operate.

Comment: Do you want to add the [tag:gratis] tag, or state a budget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you say, in comments above, that Cygwin is a possibility, that opens up the possibility of may *nix utilities, such as [sed](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/sed.htm) & [awk.](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/awk.htm)

Personally, I would code a Python script, but, if you don't code, take a look at sed & awk

Comment: Yes, this should be trivial.  May even be able to use `make` to drive it all - see the accepted answer to this question - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/354222/automating-the-virtual-host-creation-process

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend to write Python plugin for **CudaText** (or Sublime Text). Py library exists for MD, Latex, etc. Then you set a hotkey for plugin. This hotkey will generate 2 files in the folder needed, from text opened in editor.
No ready program which I know.

MD to HTML - plugin exists. Only need plugin for MD to Latex.