# Text/macro expansion program

Tags: windows, text-processing, macros

I'm looking for a simple Windows program that lets me define some macro texts that are automatically expanded when I type. Just simply "replace this string with this string".

E.g. *-abc-* expands to *abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz*

Must haves:

- It should work 'everywhere': in an editor, in my browser, in Word,...
- At least the CR(LF) should be possible in the replacement string
- Import/export of the strings. Not necessarily in the interface: if it means editing or copy a file, fine.
- Not case sensitive for the input strings
- Run under Windows 10

I don't need scripting or automating the Windows GUI, that programs like [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/) or [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) do.
Nor do I need mouse playback, or keyboard/mouse recording.

Preferably free, but a small one time fee would be OK too.

I am using [Fingertips](https://www.getfingertips.com/) right now, but that has an interface that does not work for me, and I'm looking for a (simpler) replacement.<sup>*</sup>

This is not a dupe of:

- [Is there a software alternative to hardware keyboard macros?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/52833/is-there-a-software-alternative-to-hardware-keyboard-macros), (OP wants to bind keys to keyboard shortcuts)
- [Need Help with Keyboard Macros](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/54887/need-help-with-keyboard-macros) (Op wants to monitor the screen for input)
- [Very simple macro expanding command line program in Linux and Windows](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/42071/very-simple-macro-expanding-command-line-program-in-linux-and-windows) (OP requires 'markdown' intelligence like recognizing begin/end markers)

<sup>* No resizable windows/items cut off; no multiselect items (had to delete its 40 pre-installed commands one by one); settings screen always-on-top when open; not remembering its interface settings, but insists on putting three commands back after deleting them; export option is broken and there's no import option</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at https://www.phraseexpress.com/ ? It's on my to-try list and have been recommended in various articles.

Comment: I have been running this program for a few weeks now (on one PC) and I'm happy with it. So I'll install it on all my machines.